# Update automatically property

Tags: c#, properties

I have one class :

```
public class Car
{
     public string Color { get; set; }

        public string Speed { get; set; }

        public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set automatically the value of `Property3` when property `Color` or `Speed` are updated

I want to set the value of `Property3` with the concatenation of value `Color` and `Speed` separated with hyphen

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that in the getter of `Property3` - something like this:

```
public string Property3 
{
    get { return $"{this.Color}-{this.Speed}"; }
}
```

I assume that you want `Property3` to be read only so I omitted the setter in the sample above

Comment: You might want to let the OP know that your snippet uses C# 6.0 syntax

Answer (score 1):

you can set that getter property like this

```
public string Property3 { 
   get { return Color + "-" + Speed; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

Update the dependent property within setters of speed and color:

```
private string _Color;
public string Color
{
    get
    {
        return this._Color;
    }
    set
    {
        this._Color = value;
        this.Property3 = $"{this.Color}-{this.Speed}";
    }
}

private string _Speed;
public string Speed
{
    get
    {
        return this._Speed;
    }
    set
    {
        this._Speed = value;
        this.Property3 = $"{this.Color}-{this.Speed}";
    }
}
public string Property3 { get; set; }
```

Concatenation within get of the dependent property:

```
public string Property3
{
    get
    {
        return $"{this.Color}-{this.Speed}";
    }
}
```

Conceptual difference is quite obvious: Do you want to be able to overwrite `Property3` or should it be read only.